# what makes my spinner view look different?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I tried to create a spinner and I want the view to look like this picture [image]

But why do I get a result like this [image]

Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:padding="10dip" 
android:orientation="vertical" >    
<Spinner 
android:id="@+id/spinner" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:prompt="@+string/spinner_title" 
android:drawSelectorOnTop = "true"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

And my activity

```
arrSpinner  = new Spinner(this);
List L = new ArrayList<String>();
L.add("Test 1");
L.add("Test 1");
arrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,L);
arrSpinner.setPrompt("Pilih Jawaban");
addContentView(arrSpinner, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));              
arrAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
arrSpinner.setAdapter(arrAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing the `android:spinnerMode` attribute in your XML:

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

Hope that helps!

Edit: You'll need to actually use your XML spinner in the activity as well

```
arrSpinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

...instead of:

```
arrSpinner  = new Spinner(this);
```

Comment: Thanks @ninetwozero, but it's still have the same result
any other solution?

Comment: Wait a second, are you using the Java code as well as the XML? I'll update my post accordingly.

Comment: yes of course, i use both of XML and Java Code well,
but let me see your post